# How do I fix this torn paint?

Tags: drywall, paint

I need to know how to fix this issue with a room in my house. The ceiling was removed and when it was, the paint was almost like a "flap" at the top. It got peeled and this is what i have at the top of the wall now. How should i go about fixing this before repainting?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that removing it all is out of the question so I'd start out by making a straight cut across the wall, corner to corner. Then get some joint compound and fill in the recessed area. After it dries, tape the seam like you would a normal butt joint on drywall. Now all you have to worry about is the texture. It's more than you'll get with a roller so get a few different sponges and try dipping one into some joint compound and lightly dabbing the wall with it. Try different sponges until you match the existing texture. It might take a while but keep at it. Once you've got it, prime and paint.

Comment: Yep.  Once the ceiling is replaced, skim coat with joint compound, sand it even with the old paint layer.  Apply a couple coats of a good thick primer, like Zinsser 1-2-3 in an effort to replicate the existing paint texture.  Feather out the primer, then repaint the entire wall.

Comment: If you still have paint that exactly matches, you may be able to get away with painting just this area and feathering the edge of the paint into the existing paint. Be aware that the color may look wrong until the paint is entirely dry. If that doesn't do it, you can come back and repaint the whole thing.